# How to add new row in ui-grid at specific index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to add a new row at a specific index inside the ui-grid.
So I figured out how to add a new row inside the grid but the problem is that I need to add the new row after the selected row and not on the top of the grid.

Basically I do not know how to get the index of the clicked/selected row

```
  $scope.addNew = function() {
    $scope.gridOptions.data.unshift({});  
  };
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsDVpgtpufVNhsGklXeP?p=preview) with what I have done so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything inside the code to help you, but you can do it using simply js methods.

You just need to now the entity of the selected row (for example if you're using `celNav`'s `gridApi.cellNav.on.navigate(scope,function(newRowcol, oldRowCol){})` you could get it from `newRowCol.row.entity`), then you could find its index in `gridOptions.data` by calling:

```
gridOptions.data.indexOf(rowEntity)
```

You can see how I did in a [new version](http://plnkr.co/edit/s583DdMHjxkf3yf6Gi7y?p=preview) of your plunkr.

Comment: var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf($scope.rowCol.row.entity);

this was what I was looking for. Thanks!